# 404 NOT FOUND when deploying sveltekit to vercel using turborepo, when 100% turborepo cache hit

Tags: vercel, sveltekit, turborepo

I have a turborepo with several sveltekit web apps in it. I am using caching. If one of my web apps is triggered for deployment by a repo change, and it gets a 100% turborepo cache, I get this 404 page:

[image]

---

When I turn on directory listing, just to see whats in the directory, I see this:

### [image]

And this is my vercel deployment configuration for the app:

[image]

---

The web app itself is this one - https://github.com/cozemble/monorepo/tree/main/frontend/ai-playground , so you can see all my configuration files.

When a deployment to this app is triggered by a change to the app itself (meaning turborepo caching does not happen) then it deploys fine.

**Update 1** in reponse to the question from `@paulogdm`, if I remove the `Output Directory` override, and restore it back to `public`, I get this deployment error when I deploy a fully cached turborepo build:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to remove the "Output Directory" override?

Comment: See `Update 1` to the question @paulogdm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks like there are two parts to fixing this:

1. revert the `Output Directory` override I did, so it defaults back to `public`
2. Add ".vercel/**" to your list of build outputs in `turbo.json`.  Mine now looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://turborepo.org/schema.json",
  "pipeline": {
    "build": {
      "dependsOn": ["^build"],
      "outputs": ["dist/**", "package/**", ".svelte-kit/**", ".vercel/**"]
    },
    "test": {
      "dependsOn": ["build"],
      "outputs": [],
      "inputs": []
    },
    "cypress": {
      "dependsOn": ["build", "test"],
      "inputs": ["cypress/**"],
      "outputs": []
    }
  }
}
```

Super non-obvious, but there you go.